# Refer to an unnumbered chapter in conditional

Tags: sectioning, chapters, conditionals

To add a border around a chapter I have adapted the following code from the answer here: [Vertical rectangle in every page of a single chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109800/vertical-rectangle-in-every-page-of-a-single-chapter).

```
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifthenelse{\thechapter=7}{
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
            \draw [titlegrey]($(current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+ (-1cm,-1cm)$) -- ($(current page.south east)+ (-1cm,+1cm)$) -- ($(current page.south west)+ (+1cm,+1cm)$) -- ($(current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm)$) ;
        }
%\fi
}{}
}
```

The above code adds a border to chapter 7.

However, how can I add a border to an unnumbered chapter - in this case which I label as such: `\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter with border}\label{chapborder}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a conditional as well, something like `\ifchapterborder`, which you set to be true around that specific `\chapter*`. Note that under `book`, `\chapter`s issue `\cleardoublepage`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[contents={},scale=1,opacity=1,color=black,angle=0]{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\insertborder}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
        \draw ($(current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+ (-1cm,-1cm)$) -- ($(current page.south east)+ (-1cm,+1cm)$) -- ($(current page.south west)+ (+1cm,+1cm)$) -- ($(current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm)$) ;
  }
}
\newif\ifchapterborder
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=7
    \insertborder
  \else\ifchapterborder
    \insertborder
  \fi\fi
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-20]% Chapter 1

\setcounter{chapter}{6}%
\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-20]% Chapter 7

\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-20]% Chapter 8

\cleardoublepage
\chapterbordertrue
\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter}\lipsum[1-20]
\cleardoublepage
\chapterborderfalse

\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-20]% Chapter 9

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you don't need `\cleardoublepage` if you switch the border style immediately *after* the `\chapter` commands. This way the solution works for `oneside` as well as `twoside`.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm using `report` class. I don't wat to add the blank pages before and after the chapter. Without adding `\cleardoublepage` the page proceeding the chapter to be bordered also has a border, whilst the last page of the unnumbered chapter does not have a border. Is there any possibility to solve this?

Comment: @user2568648: Then use `\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter}     \chapterbordertrue \lipsum[1-20] \chapter{A chapter}   \chapterborderfalse \lipsum[1-20]`. Essentially, issue `\chapterbordertrue` immediately after `\chapter` to activate it, and `\chapterborderfalse` immediately after the following `\chapter` to deactivate it (as mentioned by @gernot).